# AWS ALB Health Check failing for services behind Traefik

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elb, traefik

I have a TG (Target Group) with port 80. An EC2 is registered with the TG having Traefik installed. Below is my traefik.toml file:

```
debug = false
logLevel = "ERROR"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]
address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"

[retry]
[ping]

[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  watch = true
  exposedByDefault = false
```

If I `curl localhost:8080/ping`, it returns 200 OK. The same endpoint I configured in AWS ALB as:

[image: AWS ELB Health Check]

In this case, Health Checks get failed. Is there a way to let AWS ALB knows Traefik is healthy and serving?

Comment: Healthcheck endpoint needs to return a standard HTTP status code. For success its 200/OK.

Comment: Yes it services behind Traefik returns 200.

Comment: If its was returning 200/OK then you wouldn’t have an issue... Did yoi try removing the <domain> part of the healthcheck URL you provided?

Comment: Traefik is between ALB & backend services. Backend services work with ALB directly well. If we put Traefik in between, health check begins to fail in ALB.

Comment: Check the logs to see what is returned that makes it fail. Maybe you're getting a redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: ALB Health Check says "Health Check Failing".

Comment: Question simplified. Please check.

Comment: Sorry for necro but have you added port 8080 at the instance security group for incoming traffic?